# Says Celery not installed when it is

Tags: python, django, celery

I pip installed Celery. Then when I try to run celery help, I get the error that Celery is not installed.
`

```
(core)vagrant@core:/webapps/core$ celery help
The program 'celery' is currently not installed. To run 'celery' please ask your 
administrator to install the package 'python-celery'
(core)vagrant@core:/webapps/core$ pip freeze
Babel==1.3
Django==1.7.1
Fabric==1.10.0
Pillow==2.6.1
PyYAML==3.10
Werkzeug==0.9.6
amqp==1.4.6
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==3.3.0.18
celery==3.1.16
```

`

Comment: Did you install it in a venv?

Comment: Yes, django-celery is installed as well

Comment: Yes, everything is installed in a virtualenv (core)

Comment: can you try to run `celery` with the full path (`$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/celery`)

Answer (score 1):

for some reason, Celery was not properly installed the first time.

```
$pip install celery --upgrade
```

worked to get the command line tools running